# How can I get all the indexes of a Particular String in String vector in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to scala,
How can i get all the indexs for particular string.

for example:

```
var taluk = List("Hyderabad", "Nampally", "Hyderabad" ,"Khairatabad")
taluk.indexOf("Hyderabad")
```

> output is 0

But I want

> output as 0,2

because there are two string match in vector.

Comment: You should think as index of particular item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this: `zipWithIndex` and then collect the indices for values matching yours:

```
scala> taluk.zipWithIndex.collect { case ("Hyderabad", i) => i }
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 2)
```

Comment: Is there simple way to do this using find method? I mean to have general solution, including if the string not exists??

Comment: @PavelOliynyk I couldn't think of any, and neither could anyone answering the very similar question I've marked as possible duplicate (noticed it after I answered...)